# asp.net mvc and cloud: how are global data structures distributed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cloud

```
class A
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyClass> GlobalData
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    ...
}
```

Suppose `GlobalData` is used to keep some global data, with the assumption that there is only one copy of it in the entire application.
Is this assumption safe when deploying in cloud environment, where application is distributed over few "instances"? If so, then how is this done?
I guess same applies to the `Session` variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is local storage; so if you have *n* servers, you will have at least *n* instances. `ConcurrentDictionary` does not mean that it's a singleton, btw, it just means it is the thread-safe version of `Dictionary`.

If you want to have truly one global instance, one way of doing it would be to create a web service that manages access to this global data. The service would store all this data either in memory (and then there would be only one instance of the service) or in a single database. Access to its writing methods would be serialized so that only one party can be writing data at any one time.

All consumers of this service would be accessing the same data, and so the data would really be global.

Comment: So for example `Session` variable would be unreliable, right? In other words, requests with same session id might be distributed to different instances?

Comment: @ren, "Session" - you just don't use in-memory session state for deployments with more than one front end (or more than one instance of worker process in the same machine). There are SQL session state and state service implementations as part of .Net Framework. So when you use appropriate session state provider "Session" object will be correctly available on any instance that handles request.